# Play framework Scala - how to pass text from a textInput in a form into a function

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, httprequest

I am not even sure have I asked the question correctly.
I have a simple Scala Akka Spray RESTful application built. The application mimics and ATM machine, it has a withdraw and deposit functions. 
I can run it and call to it with curl. I am trying to "replace" curl now with a Play "gui" so I want to call to my Scala-Spray-Akka application.

This is my routes:

```
       # Hello action
       GET       /hello                                controllers.Application.sayHello
```

This is my controllers.Application:

```
    package controllers

    import play.api._
    import play.api.mvc._
    import play.api.data._
    import play.api.data.Forms._

    import views._

    import scalaj.http
    import scalaj.http.Http
    import play.api.libs.ws.WS
    import scala.concurrent.Future
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
    import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global


    object Application extends Controller {


      val helloForm = Form(
        tuple(
          "id" -> longNumber,
          "amountToWithdraw" -> longNumber
        )
      )

      def index = Action {
        Ok(html.index(helloForm))
      }

     def sayHello = Action.async {

       val id = 2
        WS.url("http://localhost:8080/customer/" + id).get().map { response =>
          Ok(response.body)
        }}

    }
```

index.scala.html:

```
    @(helloForm: Form[(Long, Long)])

    @import helper._

    @main(title = "The 'atm' application") {



@form(action = routes.Application.sayHello, args = 'id -> "helloform") {

    @inputText(
        field = helloForm("id"),
        args = '_label -> "What is the id of the customer?", 'size -> 3, 'placeholder -> 4
    )

    @inputText(
        field = helloForm("amountToWithdraw"),
        args = '_label -> "How much do you wish to withdraw?", 'size -> 6, 'placeholder -> 10
    )



    <p class="buttons">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Withdraw">
    <p>

}


    }


    hello.scala.html:

    @(id: Long, amountToWithdraw: Long)

    @main("Here is the result:") {



        <li>Hello customer with id @id. You want to withdraw @amountToWithdraw.</li>



<p class="buttons">
    <a href="@routes.Application.index">Back to the form</a>
</p>

    }
```

User interface:

So now I need to replace the hardcoded id number with the id number that the user will enter in the textfield in my form. How do I get that text and pass it into the id variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the line of code I was looking for:

```
 val (id, amountToWithdraw) = withdrawForm.bindFromRequest.get
```

And then I added it to the url:

```
def withdrawFunction = Action.async { implicit request =>
   val (id, amountToWithdraw) = withdrawForm.bindFromRequest.get
WS.url("http://localhost:8080/withdraw/" + id + "/" + amountToWithdraw).get().map { response =>
  Ok(response.body)
}
}
```

The route is actually a GET, not a POST:

```
GET       /depositFunction          controllers.Application.depositFunction
```

I changed the naming a bit, but the code above works.

Answer (score 0):

In `sayHello`, you'll need to get the `id` out of the form that's sent from the user's browser to your server.  You'll also need to add an entry to your routes file for that controller function:

```
POST    /sayHello   controllers.Application.sayHello
```

Then you can follow the documentation here to bind the request's body to a form: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaForms

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I know that I have to get the id number out of the form that's sent from the user's browser... I just don't know how... And I read the documentation a few times and I am still stuck... Please help with some specific code snippets.

Comment: I have tried adding a parameter to sayHello(id: Long)... I also have tried val id = helloForm("id"), but that doesnt work.

Comment: Parameters are for query strings, not form data.

Comment: Perhaps you should explore the sample forms project included with Play: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/2.2.x/samples/scala/forms